# Navigating to a specific tab from other screen in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-link

I have built a react application in which I am trying to route to a particular tab from other screen using ReactJS.
I have set route path as below:

```
<Route path="/Management" component={Management}/>
```

Here is the list of screens, for the reference.

```
-Login screen
 -Dashboard screen
 - Management screen
   -first tab
   -second tab
   -third tab
```

I want to navigate to third tab of Management screen from Dashboard screen. I have tried this using Link component. But it is navigating to first tab only.
I have given following code in dashboard screen component-

```
 <Link to="/Management">Management 3rd tab</Link>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you share how your screens and tabs are rendered by your `Router` component, i.e. what are the paths for the tab components? And if you don't have the tab components on their own routes, can you (presumably) share the `Management` component that is rendering them?

Comment: @DrewReese, yeah, I don't have different route paths for the tab components, there is only one route of management component. This is my Management component render format           
 `<div> <Tabs> <Tab href="#firstTab" id="tab-1" label="Tab1"> content1.. </Tab><Tab href="#secondTab" id="tab-2" label="Tab2"> content2.. </Tab> <Tab href="#thirdTab" id="tab-3" label="Tab3"> content3.. </Tab></Tabs> </div>`

Comment: Check out hash links: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DrewReese. But it didn't work. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I think hash-links are the right solution, but perhaps you've a different configuration. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? I'd like to see your `Router`, routes, and components with the tabs you are trying to link/navigate to.